# How to Trigger workflow B after Workflow A in Informatica without Using PMCMD Command

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

We are trying to Trigger workflow B after Workflow A has been completed in Informatica without Using PMCMD Command, Can this be Acheived using the Event wait task. The last step on workflow A is an Email task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use event wait.
After wkflow1 ends, create a file using post-session success cmd or cmd task.
Attach an event-wait to Wkflow2 in the begining. It will watch for the file created by workflow1. It must delete the file and start rest of wkflow2.
Alternately, you can use some automation tool like Automic, Cybermation, DAC etc. for better/effective control. But they will internally use PMCMD to kick off the workflows.

Answer (score 1):

In general: don't. PowerCenter does not support relationships between Workflows. So you should either go with Worklets, as suggested by @Jim. Or use a proper scheduler, like Airflow, Control-M, TWS or Autosys - pretty much as suggested by @Koushik.

It is possible to use Event-Wait/Event-Raise tasks, but these are limited features. You may go with file-based triggers and generete some files and use filewatchers. There are some options, but using a dedicated tool that will truly support dependencies and that will be able to show the dependencies is the proper way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Worklet, which will provide you the order of the execution of  workflows